# Conan-based Qt installation uses wrong home dir for linking

Tags: qt, conan

I'm trying to build our application using Qt 5.13.0 installed via Conan/Artifactory. We run our own Artifactory server and the Qt version there is self-build (and statically linked) in our CI solution. We use the [Conan recipe for Qt written by the bincrafters](https://github.com/bincrafters/conan-qt), slightly modified to apply some patches for known Qt bugs and set some flags for building properly on Android and WebAssembly.

When trying to build the application, the linker fails to find the necessary dependencies for Qt itself because it tries to look them up in the home folder of the user who build the Qt package, not the user who's running the build.

Here's an excerpt from the build log, showing the attempt at linking all previously compiled object files together:

```
       application folder-------v        subproject of the application----v-------v       dependency of the application, correct user home dir---------v                                             Qt library installed via Conan, correct user home dir-------v                                                            dependency of Qt, WRONG user home dir------------v
g++ -Wl,--gc-sections -o ../../fah [--> all the .o files <--] -L../lib -lmodel -lcore [--> more linked libraries and application parts <--] -L/home/kaupes/.conan/data/libsodium/1.0.18/bje/stable/package/d1efe3774eed76670888f919621e7c4e1b52efa9/lib  /home/kaupes/.conan/data/qt/5.13.0/bje/stable/package/d6b3f512e1a5607061462f94e3271dc8af3dd516/lib/libQt5Gui.a /home/dev/.conan/data/harfbuzz/2.4.0/bje/stable/package/c68551ae35bf5d62e66263379d58a38416eb84a9/lib/libharfbuzz.a [--> many, many more libraries <--]
g++: error: /home/dev/.conan/data/harfbuzz/2.4.0/bje/stable/package/c68551ae35bf5d62e66263379d58a38416eb84a9/lib/libharfbuzz.a: No such file or directory
many, many more errors...
```

As you can see, the user running the build is `kaupes`, but the `g++` invocation attempts to look for the dependencies in `/home/dev/`, the home folder of the CI user who build the Qt Conan package.

Only dependencies of Qt itself have the problem. Dependencies of the application (also installed via Conan) are found at the correct place.

The Qt package has been build in the CI using the following Conan invocation:

```
conan create --profile .conan/profiles/linux -s compiler=gcc -s compiler.version=9 . fah/stable
```

Compiler and version are explicitly set because I'm also build for another GCC version. The `linux` profile file also doesn't do anything interesting (as far as I can see):

```
include(default)

[settings]
build_type=Release
compiler.libcxx=libstdc++11

[options]
OpenSSL:shared=False
OpenSSL:no_asm=True
OpenSSL:no_asm=True
OpenSSL:no_weak_ssl_ciphers=True
OpenSSL:no_ssl2=True
OpenSSL:no_ssl3=True
OpenSSL:no_engine=True
libcurl:shared=False
libxml2:shared=False
libxml2:fPIC=True
libsodium:shared=False

pcre2:shared=False
libpng:shared=False
freetype:shared=False
bzip2:shared=False
libjpeg:shared=False
harfbuzz:shared=False
xkbcommon:shared=False
qt:shared=False
qt:with_glib=False
qt:with_sqlite3=False
qt:with_mysql=False
qt:with_pq=False
qt:with_odbc=False
qt:with_sdl2=False
qt:with_openal=False
qt:with_libalsa=False
qt:openssl=True
qt:commercial=False
qt:qtsvg=True
qt:qtdeclarative=True
qt:qtactiveqt=False
qt:qtscript=False
qt:qtmultimedia=False
qt:qttools=True
qt:qtxmlpatterns=False
qt:qttranslations=True
qt:qtdoc=False
qt:qtrepotools=False
qt:qtqa=False
qt:qtlocation=True
qt:qtsensors=True
qt:qtwayland=True
qt:qt3d=False
qt:qtimageformats=False
qt:qtgraphicaleffects=True
qt:qtquickcontrols=True
qt:qtserialbus=False
qt:qtserialport=False
qt:qtx11extras=True
qt:qtmacextras=False
qt:qtwinextras=False
qt:qtandroidextras=False
qt:qtwebsockets=True
qt:qtwebchannel=False
qt:qtwebengine=False
qt:qtwebview=False
qt:qtquickcontrols2=True
qt:qtpurchasing=False
qt:qtcharts=True
qt:qtdatavis3d=False
qt:qtvirtualkeyboard=True
qt:qtgamepad=False
qt:qtscxml=False
qt:qtspeech=False
qt:qtnetworkauth=False
qt:qtremoteobjects=False
qt:qtwebglplugin=False
qt:qtlottie=False
qt:qtconnectivity=True
```

Is there something I'm doing wrong during the Conan package creation or installation or is this caused by something different?

Comment: from where did you download this Qt package? there is no information about the package in your description. Please, include the package reference.

Comment: We download this from our own Artifactory server, after building Qt in our CI using the Conan recipe from the bincrafters. I added a link to the first paragraph of my opening post. The build environment, if important, is a Docker container running Fedora 30 with the necessary packages installed. All Qt dependencies our selected options need we also build in our CI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, when building qt, all paths to dependencies are hardcoded in configurations files (mkspecs\modules\qt_lib_*.pri).
I assume you are building your application with qmake, because you use static qt, and static qt is incompatible with cmake. One thing you could try is to pass the full path to harfbuzz lib to qmake by adding argument `QMAKE_LIBS_HARFBUZZ=/home/kaupes/.conan/data/harfbuzz/2.4.0/bje/stable/package/c68551ae35bf5d62e66263379d58a38416eb84a9/lib/libharfbuzz.a` to your qmake invocation.

Edit: it seems to be a knwonw behaviour of qt >= 5.12.1 : https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-72903. This feature has been reverted in 5.14.x and 5.15.x with https://github.com/qt/qtbase/commit/9864d2c6f3b628ca9f07a56b197e77bd43931cca

Comment: Thanks, that gave me the information needed to start on my solution. While setting paths to the libraries using environment variables didn't work, I added a `deploy` method the our Conan recipe that replaces all of the paths with paths that lead to the building user's home directory. Not exactly elegant, but it seems to work fine so far.

Comment: My answer was not clear enough. you should not add environment variable to the qmake invocation by putting `QMAKE_LIBS_HARFBUZZ=..` before `qmake ...`, but you should instead use command line arguments by calling `qmake QMAKE_LIBS_HARFBUZZ=...`. QMAKE_LIBS_HARFBUZZ is a qmake variable, not an environment variable